# Lint: How to ignore "<key> is not translated in <language>" errors?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, localization, android-resources, android-lint

I can't compile/debug our Android app, because the localization files are not perfect yet.

My IDE's validation tool [Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/) create errors saying:

> newCardsOrderVals is not translated in ar, bg, ca, cs

Compiling/installing/running with Ant works fine, but I would like to use my IDE to ease debugging.

Is there a way to turn off this particular check, or ideally make it a warning rather than an error?

I understand that before release we will really need to get localisation files right, but for the time being it is not a priority as the screens themselves are being modified very frequently.

Comment: Is there a way to configure which all languages are flagged as "not translated?" I get errors like "es, he, and iw". Why do I get those languages? How do I configure my Android app to restrict the set to "en" only?

Comment: @inder: Maybe because you have directories like "values-he" etc in your res/ folder?

Comment: No, I dont have any such directories. Only, values, layout, and drawable.

Comment: es, he and iw come from the Facebook SDK library.

Comment: This is a bug in Android Lint: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=50525

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Android Studio:

- "File" > "Settings" and type "MissingTranslation" into the search box

Eclipse:

- Windows/Linux: In "Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"
- Mac: "Eclipse" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"

Find the `MissingTranslation` line, and set it to `Warning` as seen below:

[image: Missing translations, is not translated in]

Comment: ... It's under "Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"

Comment: FYI under  Android Studio it's "File" > "Settings" and "MissingTranslation" into the search box.

Answer (score 86):

You can set the attribute translatable="false" on the  definition like this:

```
<string name="account_setup_imap" translatable="false">IMAP</string>
```

For more information: http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings

Comment: I said "the localization files are not perfect **yet**". They are being filled little by little. translatable="false" would prevent anybody from translating.

Comment: While the answer is not directly related to the question, I guess, it provide brilliant solution for folks like me who found this topic when Google "how to make lint don't worry about my app constants/parameters". Thank you, efor18!

Answer (score 83):

To ignore this in a gradle build add this to the android section of your build file:

```
lintOptions {
   disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, literally saved me days of finding all the correct strings for production.

Comment: Nice one, this did it

Comment: Added this to my app module soved it for me.

Answer (score 23):

This will cause Lint to ignore the missing translation error for ALL strings in the file, yet other string resource files can be verified if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
```

Comment: This is probably the most correct way to proceed, without disabling lint for all the project

Answer (score 11):

If you want to turn off the warnings about the specific strings, you can use the following:

*strings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    

    <!--suppress MissingTranslation -->
    <string name="some_string">ignore my translation</string>
    ...

</resources>
```

If you want to warn on specific strings instead of an error, you will need to build a custom Lint rule to adjust the severity status for a specific thing.

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Comment: +1 Good way to do it once for all, so that all developers of the team don't have to modify their IDE settings. Any way to make it a warning, rather than suppress completely?

Comment: You can build a custom Lint rule to adjust the severity status for a specific thing. There is an example here: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Answer (score 9):

Insert in the `lint.xml` file this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    ...

    <issue
        id="MissingTranslation"
        severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

For more details: [Suppressing Lint Warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings).

Answer (score 9):

add the lines in your /res/values.xml file in resource root tab like this:

```
<resources
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:locale="en" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
```

tools:locale set the local language to English, no need of language translation later on that for all resource strings and tools:ignore let Lint to isnore the missing translations of the resource string values.

Answer (score 6):

Add following to your gradle file in android section

```
    lintOptions {
       disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition,

Not project dependent properities, Eclipse Preferences.
In Mac, Eclipse > Preferences

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to indicate the languages you intend to support and filter out the rest using the 'resConfigs' option with Gradle.

Check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013558/1145905) for details

This is better, I think, because you don't have to completely ignore legitimate translation mistakes for languages you actually want to support

Answer (score 1):

You can also put resources which you do not want to translate to file called `donottranslate.xml`.

Example and explanation: http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings

Comment: this is the best way to do it and it's organized.

Answer (score 1):

Many of them has a given a different working answers, and i too got the same lint errors
i make it ignore by doing the following with eclipse.

1. click on Windows
2. click on preferences
3. select android > Lint Error Checking.
4. click on ignore All > Apply > Ok.

Thats it.

Comment: this will ignore all lint preferences. Not only the Missing Translation

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

- Click on Windows
- Click on preferences
- Select android > Lint Error Checking.
- Find and select the relevant Lint checking and
- Set the severity to 'Ignore' (on bottom right)