# Android Lint asks to translate strings to MANY languages which i don't use in app

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, lint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lint: How to ignore “<key> is not translated in <language>” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443996/lint-how-to-ignore-key-is-not-translated-in-language-errors)

I have encountered strange problem.

When i try to export signed application i see errors like

```
"app_name" is not translated in af, am, ar, be, bg, ca, cs, da, de, el, en-rGB, es, es-rUS, et, fa, fi, fr, hi, hr, hu, in, it, iw, ja, ko, lt, lv, ms, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt-rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr,  uk, vi, zh-rCN, zh-rTW, zu
```

Perhaps it is because i use Maps API v2.

Is there any solution for this problem apart disabling lint checks?

Comment: Ignore it!  You've got a string value in strings.xml which you haven't localised.  It's just a Lint warning.  To answer your question, copy the value to each locale res folder.

Comment: Simple answer: "Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking". Type in "MissingTranslation" and change it to "Warning"