# Android Export signed application package error

Tags: android, xml, api, export, apk

When I try to export signed application package for google mao, I get this error on my res/value/string.xml file. What should i do?

```
app_name" is not translated in af, am, ar, be, bg, ca, cs, da, de, el, en-rGB, es, es-rUS, et, fa, fi, fr, hi, hr, hu, in, it, iw, ja, ko, lt, lv, ms, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt-rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr, uk, vi, zh-rCN, zh-rTW, zu
Issue: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
Id: MissingTranslation
If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared in one language should also be translated in all other languages.
If the string should not be translated, you can add the attribute translatable="false" on the <string> element, or you can define all your non-translatable strings in a resource file called donottranslate.xml. Or, you can ignore the issue with a tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" attribute.
By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide a subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language strings. You can require all regions to provide a full translation by setting the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.
You can tell lint (and other tools) which language is the default language in your res/values/ folder by specifying tools:locale="languageCode" for the root <resources> element in your resource file. (The tools prefix refers to the namespace declaration http://schemas.android.com/tools.)
```

Comment: Did you create folders of the form `value-af`, `value-am`, etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lint: How to ignore "<key> is not translated in <language>" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443996/lint-how-to-ignore-key-is-not-translated-in-language-errors)

Answer (score 39):

In `"Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"`:

Go to `MissingTranslation` line, and set it to Warning:

[image]

Comment: this did not worked for me. I am stil getting the error

Answer (score 11):

Try this

Go to Eclipse -> Window tab -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint error checking -> uncheck the full error check run

might be it could helpful

Answer (score 6):

In the string.xml file just add `translatable="false"` to the string. just like this

```
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">Example App</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although all of the other answers are correct, another option is to add the `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"` attribute to the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" >

    <!-- your strings here; no need now for the translatable attribute -->
</resources>
```

I prefer this because a) it doesn't require changing *every* string value, and b) it's not an application setting so it can be checked into git. On the other hand, it won't help if the errors are in referenced projects that you don't have write access to.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the string.xml file to donottranslate.xml. Might this will help you.