# string.xml translatable error in android while signing apk

Tags: android, string, apk, lint

even after using translatable="false" getting lint error for strings while signing apk.

values/strings.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources >
         <string name="app_name" translatable="false">my app name</string>
         <string ...</string>
         <string ....</string>
    </resources >
```

added translatable="false" in all string but not working.getting

```
app_name is translated here but not found in default locale
```

is there any solution?

android support v7 appcompat strings.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>
    <!-- Label for the "Done" button on the far left of action mode toolbars. -->
    <string name="abc_action_mode_done" translatable="false">Done</string>
    <!-- Content description for the action bar "home" affordance. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description" translatable="false">Navigate home</string>
    <!-- Content description for the action bar "up" affordance. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_action_bar_up_description" translatable="false">Navigate up</string>
    <!-- Content description for the action menu overflow button. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description" translatable="false">More options</string>

    <!-- SearchView accessibility description for search button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_search" translatable="false">Search</string>
    <!-- SearchView accessibility description for search text field [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_query" translatable="false">Search query</string>
    <!-- SearchView accessibility description for clear button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_clear" translatable="false">Clear query</string>
    <!-- SearchView accessibility description for submit button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_submit" translatable="false">Submit query</string>
    <!-- SearchView accessibility description for voice button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_voice" translatable="false">Voice search</string>

    <!-- ActivityChooserView - accessibility support -->
    <!-- Description of the shwoing of a popup window with activities to choose from. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application" translatable="false">Choose an app</string>
    <!-- Title for a button to expand the list of activities in ActivityChooserView [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
    <string name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all" translatable="false">See all</string>
    <!-- Description of a share target (both in the list of such or the default share button) in a ShareActionProvider (share UI). [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application" translatable="false">Share with %s</string>
    <!-- Description of the choose target button in a ShareActionProvider (share UI). [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with" translatable="false">Share with</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: have you provide multiple language (string) for your app ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631994/android-export-signed-application-package-error may help you

Comment: @Haresh no.for that i have used translatable="false" in string tag.getting this error for appcompt v7 & google play service lib

Comment: @PankajKumar referred that linked also.but not resolved my problem

Comment: have you added this translatable="false" lib default string ?

Comment: Yes. read my question again. its already there

Comment: Check : http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings

Comment: just clean your project and again signing apk

Comment: @DigveshPatel Did many times.getting problem each time

Comment: if you remove this line translatable="false" than wt happen have you checked?

Comment: I think which ever string you don't wan to translate in other language then simply give this attribute to string default file and don't try to define this string other strings file as per above line.

Comment: @DigveshPatel eve if i dont include translatable="false" getting same error

Comment: ... do you have other strings.xml files? is there your string `app_name` translated? If so, remove it from ALL the strings.xml files other than the default one.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein google play service lib & appcompatv7 have other languages string.xml

Comment: NO. I mean YOUR app structure. No other things, which are out of discussion.

Comment: No.im my app structer there is no other string.xml files

Comment: So, you don't need the `translatable="false"`, since it will never be translated (you didn't provide translations). SOLVED.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i'm getting this problem for google play service library & appcompat library

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60206/discussion-on-question-by-yuva--string-xml-translatable-error-in-android-while).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your Lint.xml`<issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="ignore" />`