# Set translated languages in application

Tags: android

The default language of my app is English and I translated it into German. But now if I want to export it as an signed application in Eclipse there comes many errors that all string are not translated in other languages like es, fr , it and so on.

How can I export my app as signed application with only two languages and ignore all other languages?

Comment: which errors do you get. Got a logcat output that You can show here?

Comment: disable lint error checking and compile

Comment: I get the error: `"AddItem" is not translated in ca, fr, ga, it, ja, ko, nl pl, pt-rBR, zh-rCN`. How can I disable lint error checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to translate your app if you don't want to. Just check that all strings are defined in the base `values/` folder. Then you can create more `values-XX/` folders with their own `strings.xml` with all of the strings (or just a fraction of them). Android will take the default string if it doesn't find the localised version of the string.

If you are not localising to other languages, make sure that their values folder are not defined. For example, if you are not localising to Spanish, make sure that you don't have the `values-es/` folder in your `res/` folder.

EDIT: Same topic solved: [Lint: How to ignore "<key> is not translated in <language>" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443996/lint-how-to-ignore-key-is-not-translated-in-language-errors)

Comment: I don't have the other folders in my project.