# Missing translation errors in Android

Tags: android, xml, api, export

When exporting a signed android package I get the following error:

```
app_name to translated in es,he,iw
```

No where in my app I have defined these three languages.  I am not able to understand how lint is coming up with these languages.  Is there any configuration that I might have updated my mistake?

I know that I can turn off this lint error by going to Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking > MissingTranslation.  But that is not what I want to do.  I have no plans to translate my app to these languages, then from where are these errors showing up.

Is there any file where I can define that my application uses only one locale?

Comment: Further clarification: The reason that I do not want to turn off this error, but rather fix it, is because when I upload this to Google Play store it says 3 languages added which I have not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.  I am using FacebookSDK as a library function which has the folders values-es, values-he, values-iw which the android-lint is also expecting in my project.

To fix my issues I have removed these folders from FacebookSDK and recompiled my application.

However I do not think android lint should be flagging these as errors as they are not being used in my project, but that would be a different discussion.

To generalize the answer for the benefit of other developers stumbling here:

1. Check if you have created any values- folders, eg values-es, values-he, values-iw. If yes and you do not plan to use them remove the folders.
2. If you have not created the values- folders check if you these folders are present in any library project that you have referenced.  If not needed in the library project remove them and recompile.
   Note: If you remove folders from library project make sure to back them up as you may require them later.

Comment: Instead of removing Facebook SDK folder you should follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444141/826606

Answer (score 0):

you missed to mention the app_name in the all **string.xml** files  , you may mention in only on one values file , but not in other two lang values . please check it.

```
values-en

values-he

values-iw
```

you have to mention in above three folders also..

Answer (score 0):

Check your project, whether you have these folders in res/: `values-es`, `values-he`, `values-iw`.

If you donot want to support these languages, delete them.

If you want to support some languages, each `strings.xml` need have `app_name` item.