# Error exporting signed application package

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create a SHA-1 key for my android application so that I can enable google maps, however after pressing the "export signed application" button I get the following error.

> ""app_name" is not translated in af, am, ar, be, bg, ca, cs, da, de,
>   el, en-rGB, en-rIN, es, es-rUS, et, et-rEE, fa, fi, fr, fr-rCA, hi,
>   hr, hu, hy-rAM, in, it, iw, ja, ka-rGE, km-rKH, ko, lo-rLA, lt, lv,
>   mn-rMN, ms, ms-rMY, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt- rBR, pt-rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl,
>   sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr, uk, vi, zh-rCN, zh-rHK, zh-rTW, zu".

The first time I did an export of this type it worked however now this error is being returned as a "lint warning". Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can see some info at this post:

[Lint: How to ignore "<key> is not translated in <language>" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443996/lint-how-to-ignore-key-is-not-translated-in-language-errors)

Basically, the latest tools do a lint check before allowing you to export.

You can disable it under

"Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"

You should be able to disable

"Run full error check when exporting app and abort if fatal errors are found".

I'm guessing that if you distribute to different locales, your app will not function as expected, that's why the tools consider that a "fatal" error.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as if your `app_name` had been declared in a language localized resource folder (values-en).

Try creating a resource file in `values`, that will be the lowest level value found of no other localizations are available.