# Error in xml file in android

Tags: android

i am having an unexpected error in the strings.xml file stored in values folder of my project.
The error is shown at name="niceweekend_msgs"
My code is:

```
<string-array name="niceweekend_msgs">
        <item>Better days are coming. They are called Saturday and Sunday.\n
Have a nice weekend!</item>
</string-array>
```

The error shown is:

"niceweekend_msgs" is not translated in af, am, ar, bg, ca, cs, da, de, el, en-rGB, en-rIN, es, es-rUS, et-rEE, fa, fi, fr, fr-rCA, hi, hr, hu, 
 hy-rAM, in, it, iw, ja, ka-rGE, km-rKH, ko, lo-rLA, lt, lv, mn-rMN, ms-rMY, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt-rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr, uk, vi, 
 zh-rCN, zh-rHK, zh-rTW, zu

Comment: Is it actually an error or a warning?

Comment: error. My project is completed. Suddenly while exporting it occured. Pathetic. I was about to upload the project in google play. Pease suggest me something.

Comment: Does it keep it from compiling?

Comment: yup it couldn't be compiled . I know that should not be error. I couldn't found a way out. At last i copied and pasted that strings file with some other name. Now it is working fine. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a warning for missing translations.

go to the preferences (`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`) and set "`Missing Translation`" to warning or ignore.

Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443996/lint-how-to-ignore-key-is-not-translated-in-language-errors)

Comment: accept the answer (the tick) and rate it up (the up arrow) if it helped =) Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You have only one string. For that you can do this :-

```
<string name="account_setup_imap" translatable="false">IMAP</string>
```

Right click project -> Properties ->Android Lint Preferences

Type Missing Translation in the Search bar on the right side.

Select **MissingTranslation** in the list below under **Correctness Messages** ->

Select Severity(Bottom-right) to warning or ignore.

Comment: Again i am having the problem while exporting. Actually it is an array. I have mentioned only one item above. Can you tell me now how to resolve?

Comment: @user3080161 - Edited Code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I have added this lines to gradle file in Android Studio.

Then problem solved about missing translations.

```
android {
     lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```