# android error in String.xml

Tags: android, xml

i didn't actually make use of it anywhere in the app, and app was running fine ( i still have an .apk backup )  but when i tried to Export .apk file through Eclipse , suddenly error appeared in String.xml file :

```
<string name="app_name">PUCIT Aggregate Calculator</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_data">Data</string>
```

there is a error mark (red cross before all these four lines ) saying :

"title_activity_data" is not translated in af, am, ar, bg, ca, cs, da, de, el, en-rGB, en-rIN, es, es-rUS, et-rEE, fa, fi, fr, fr-rCA, hi, hr, hu, hy-rAM, in, it, iw, ja, ka-rGE, km-rKH, ko, lo-rLA, lt, lv, mn-rMN, ms-rMY, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt-
 rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr, uk, vi, zh-rCN, zh-rHK, zh-rTW, zu

Comment: Did you try Lint Error Checking?

Comment: Do you have some alternative values folders? Such as values-de, or values-pl?

Comment: Do you have other languages files ?

Comment: Try Ignoring LINT Error Checking

Comment: Your project -> Properties -> Android Lint Preferences -> MissingTranslation (ignore it and it will be ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an ignorable warning because of missing translations.

Navigate to the preferences (`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`) and set "`Missing Translation`" to WARNING or IGNORE.

You can try as per suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476051/3492139) (Not verified)

```
<string name="title_activity_data" translatable="false">Data</string>
```

Comment: tried this : 
<string name="title_activity_data" translatable="false">Data</string>
 error in last line is gone .... now what about 3 above ... :!

Comment: and i haven't found abt LINT here .....
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

there is just SDK location setting  in Window -> Preferences -> Android , nothing else

Answer (score 0):

It's just a lint check, you've probably added the localised folders to your project and it is complaining. You can change the type of error for these issues on Eclipse and make them to be 'warning' instead of 'error'. You can go to your Eclipse -> Preferences ...search for Lint and then you can change the type of the errors for 'Missing Translation'.